# desktop application layers

Tags: java, architecture, layer

I'm begining a desktop application (SWT/JFACE), for create, read, update and delete entries from a database.

I want to do this the right way, so the application will be easy to extend.

That's why i am looking for how desktop applications developement can be divided in layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you should look at how MVC (model-view-controller) pattern could be applied to seperate presentation, business logic and data layers.
Also Hibernate could be used to do those CRUD operations even if it's not a web application.